# PHP carousel only shows top of video?

Tags: html, video, carousel

I have this carousel on my php site with a video in it (and two pictures), but it only shows the top of the video? Can I get it to take the center of the video instead of the top?

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-pause="hover">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="fill embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <video autoplay class="embed-responsive-item">
                <source src="media/Videologo.mp4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/Forside.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/Arrangementer.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

Comment: This question seems like it is an HTML/CSS related question not a PHP question.

Comment: is it really a 16:9 video?? if it's a 4:3 video i guess you can change the class embed-responsive-16by9  to embed-responsive-4by3.   see if that helps

Comment: Sorry about the HTML/CSS - PHP stuff (I'm completely new to all this, so I basically know nothing).

aampudia, if I change it to 4:3 it makes the video small so I have big black spaces on each side of the video (in the 16:9 it reaches from one side to the other, but it only takes the top of the video. I don't want it to show the entire height of the video, but I would like it to show the middle of it)